# Unread mail can't be get in NewmailEx event in outlook

Tags: c#, outlook

- i want delete attachment when new mail receiving.....
- so i use NewmailEx event.....and also tried Newmail event.....
- i open the outlook --> send a mail to my outlook mail -->the event get fired -->but the received mail is not shown in my unread mail i.e, c# coding didn't get the received mail (this happen only for the first mail..after closing and opening of outlook..from the second mail the operation works correctly)

i attach my code below

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    this.Application.NewMail += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook
       .ApplicationEvents_11_NewMailEventHandler(ThisApplication_NewMail);
}
private void ThisApplication_NewMail()
{
    Outlook.MAPIFolder inBox = this.Application.ActiveExplorer()
        .Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook
        .OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
    Outlook.Items inBoxItems = inBox.Items;
    Outlook.MailItem newEmail = null;
    inBoxItems = inBoxItems.Restrict("[Unread] = true");

    foreach (object collectionItem in inBoxItems)
    {
        newEmail = collectionItem as Outlook.MailItem;
        if (newEmail != null)
        {
            if (newEmail.Attachments.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= newEmail
                   .Attachments.Count; i++)
                {
                    newEmail.Attachments[1].Delete();

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me to read the first mail.....when outlook was open...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you use the [NewMail](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869202(v=office.15).aspx) event, but not the [NewMailEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863686(v=office.15).aspx) one.

The NewMailEx event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID returned in the EntryIDCollection array to call the NameSpace.GetItemFromID method and process the item. Use this method with caution to minimize the impact on Outlook performance. However, depending on the setup on the client computer, after a new message arrives in the Inbox, processes like spam filtering and client rules that move the new message from the Inbox to another folder can occur asynchronously. You should not assume that after these events fire, you will always get a one-item increase in the number of items in the Inbox.

You may also find the following series of articles helpful:

- [Outlook NewMail event unleashed: the challenge (NewMail, NewMailEx, ItemAdd)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/03/outlook-newmail-event/)
- [Outlook NewMail event: solution options](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/24/outlook-newmail-solution-options/)
- [Outlook NewMail event and Extended MAPI: C# example](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/01/outlook-newmail-extended-mapi/)
- [Outlook NewMail unleashed: writing a working solution (C# example)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/10/outlook-newmail-custom-solution/)